# Thoughtworks Go Agent : Registration configuration

Tags: java, continuous-integration, thoughtworks-go

Today only I heard about the Thoughtworks GO and started the installation configuration. Windows Installation is went well and I am able to run the server over HTTP using 8153 ports.

Then I have installed agent in the same box using the localhost. What i am not able to figure out is how to connect the agent automatically using HTTP ? I am getting error in the go agent log that is trying to access the `https : //localhost :8153` I am right now not concerned with HTTPS and all. all I want to register the Agent.

One more thing just for FYI. I have enabled user authentication file based. that is working fine.

Please suggest if there is alternate way to change the URL Protocol to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I run the manual installation by downloading the zip for the go server and then I got the server running with both HTTP and HTTPS without any additional efforts.

This answer will be useful is the installation is having issue with the windows installer. Use the zip.

Thanks. 
Praveen